# How would you write a batch file to check that versions successfully updated in a package.json, appsettings.json and csproj file?

Tags: javascript, c#, batch-file

I need to check that the version number updated for javascript and c# microservices which wastes hours of time after checking several new branch updates. Is this possible? The version updating is done via another batch file. I was googling around but I didn't see a git command or anything to check.

Any help would be appreciated.

What I was trying so far was

```bash
set check1="1111.1.1"
set check2="11111" 

set app=javascriptProject
cd %app%
rem -- need to check version number of the package.json --

cd ..

set app=c#project
cd %app.APIService%
rem -- need to check the version number of the app.APIService.csproj and the appsettings.json --

cd...

pause
```

Comment: _"I didn't see a git command"_ - why would `git` be of any use here?

Comment: git commands were used in the other batch files to pull in the current version of everything so I assumed git was the way to go about this.

Comment: I’m curious - can you share examples of how that works? I’m genuinely interested

Comment: "set app=projectName  cd %app% git stash -u git fetch git pull origin cd .. pause" it wouldn't let me put those on different lines